# convert SelfExpandingBufferredInputStream to poi XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, rest, io, apache-poi

Im getting SelfExpandingBufferredInputStream from client response and I want to convert it into poi XSSFWorkbook. But Im getting below error,

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RESTEASY003000:
> SelfExpandingBufferredInputStream is always marked at index 0.    at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.SelfExpandingBufferredInputStream.mark(SelfExpandingBufferredInputStream.java:39)
> at java.io.FilterInputStream.mark(FilterInputStream.java:201)

below is the sample code used to feed XSSFWorkbook,

```
final Response httpResponse = webTarget.path(REQUEST_PATH).resolveTemplate("docId", docId)
                    .request("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")// same error with and without this
                    .header(RequestInvokerConstants.ACCEPT_TYPE, MediaType.WILDCARD )
                    .header("context", context).get();
             InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.readEntity(InputStream.class);
             Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream); //getting error in this line
```

restClient.downloadDocument response will be, "ClientResponse$InputStreamWrapper" and that will be assigned to InputStream

[image]

poi-ooxml and poi version is 4.1.2

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Looks like you have an `InputStream` which doesn't fully comply with the specification. Try wrapping in a `BufferedInputStream` ?

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks for replying. Tried with that also before but getting same exception